# I forgot to check the "change ownership" box for S3 replication - any way to update existing replicated objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using S3 replication to copy a bucket across AWS accounts (both are in the same region).

When originally I set up the replication I didn't notice that I had to check the "change ownership" box in order to allow access to the objects in the destination bucket (the original bucket is using AES-256 encryption).

I realized this after I have a couple of Terabytes already copied over to the other account.

Is there any way to update the existing copied objects in the destination bucket to allow access so that I do not have to copy them all over again?

FYI - To perform the copy I used cross-region replication with the copy to itself method as shown here in an AWS knowledge center page (see the " Use cross-Region replication or same-Region replication " section)-

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/

If anyone knows of a faster or better way I am all ears!!

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through all the objects and update the ACL. This needs to be done using credentials from the originating "owner" account of the object.

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket XX --key XX --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

I just did an experiment:

- Copied an object from Account-A to Account-B
- Account-B could not run the above command because it was not the bucket owner
- Account-A *could* run the command
- After that, Account-B could run the command, indicating that ownership had changed

The easiest method would be to write a small script (eg in Python) that gets a listing of the bucket and issues the `put_object_acl()` command using credentials from the original account. Or, if you don't feel confident writing that, simply create an Excel spreadsheet with the filenames and a formula to generate the above command.

It would be best to run the commands from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region as the bucket, since communications will be faster than doing it from your own computer.